# JPA relations between entities. How to make Entity take from DB only some field from relationed table

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, foreign-keys, mapping

I have got two entities with Many-to-one (One-to-many) relationship.

**Class ParserEntity:**

```
import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "parser", schema = "newsmonitoringdb")
public class ParserEntity {
    public ParserEntity() {
    }

    public ParserEntity(String name, SourceTypesEntity type) {
        this.name = name;
        this.type = type;
    }

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    @Basic
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name="type",referencedColumnName="id")
    private SourceTypesEntity type;

    ...//getters, setters and other fields are here
    }
}
```

**Class ParserTypesEntity:**

```
import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by User on 17.08.2016.
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "source_types", schema = "newsmonitoringdb")
public class ParserTypesEntity {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    @Basic
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="type", fetch=FetchType.EAGER, targetEntity = ParserEntity.class)
    private Collection<ParserEntity> siteParser;

    ...//getters and setters are here
    }
}
```

They have a relation by field and everything seems ok. 
However I would like a ParserTypeEntity class to save only names from ParserEntity class in a separate Collection field instead of ParserEntity list.

I would like them to be filled automatically when retrieving types from DB the same way it is done with ParserEntity objects now.

Is there any way to do that, or I have to change the relation to the unidirectional one, get all of the types and then get names for each type by its id?

Comment: It saves what your model has (as all JPA docs say). Fix your model so you have a Collection of String, and populate it.

Comment: I tried to create OneToMany field without "mappedBy" and "targerEntity" parameters. I made a collection save string parameters, but the compiler tells OneToMany attribute value type should not be "String"

Comment: Obviously `@OneToMany` should not be used ... that is for relations. You want to store a Collection of String ... which needs `@ElementCollection`! Suggest you read JPA tutorials which explain these concepts

Answer (score 0):

> They have a relation by field and everything seems ok. However I would
>   like a ParserTypeEntity class to save only names from ParserEntity
>   class in a separate Collection field instead of ParserEntity list.
>
> I would like them to be filled automatically when retrieving types
>   from DB the same way it is done with ParserEntity objects now.

I don't think that you can use converter for relation with collections.
Besides, even if you could, I would not use it since it could make the code less natural and less readable. For an enum, it's useful and overall cosmetic but for entity collection, it looks like a hack since it breaks the ORM relationship between entities.

If you use `JPA/EntityManager`, I can propose a workaround : using a lifecycle event of entities. Otherwise, if you use Hibernate/SessionFactory, you should look listeners for Hibernate. It's the same principle.

The idea is keeping your actual mapping and adding a transient list with data you wish which would be populated in an automatic way when a `ParserTypesEntity` is loaded.

So, in `ParserTypesEntity`, you can add a hook method to do a processing when the entity is loaded. In this method, you could collect names of `parserEntity` collection and add it in a `transient List<String>`.

```
public class ParserTypesEntity {
 ...
  @Transient
  private List<String> parserTypeNames;

  @PostLoad
  public void postLoad() {
    parserTypeNames = new ArrayList<>();
    for (ParserEntity parserEntity : siteParser){
      parserTypeNames.add(parserEntity.getName());
   }
  ...
}
```

Comment: I am using JPA/EntityManager and your solutions seems interesting, but it still need the downloading of all of the parserEntities from DB, which I am trying to avoid (I have already changed Fetching to the LAZY type instead of EAGER). I demand such thing, because at this point application needs only names of all of Entities in DB. It will require some  objects, taken from db fully a bit later, but there will be no need in all of them in 90% of usage.